# PHP writing wierd chars from python request

Tags: php, python, sql, serial-port

I have a python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import time
import datetime
import serial
from time import strftime
import urllib2, urllib

datetimeWrite = (time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d ") + time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))

ser = serial.Serial(
        port='/dev/ttyUSB0',
        baudrate = 4800,
        parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
        stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
        bytesize=serial.SEVENBITS,
        timeout=10 ## Tempo de espera para leitura
)

card=ser.read(size=16)

if len(card) == 16:
        result=card
else:
        result="20ERROR20"

id = 1

mydata=[('idLeitor','1'),('leitura',result),('time',datetimeWrite)]
mydata=urllib.urlencode(mydata)
path='http://0.0.0.0:8080/core/db.card.read.php'
req=urllib2.Request(path, mydata)
req.add_header("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
page=urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
print page
```

When I pass the card on the reader /dev/ttyUSB0 on the console I get this:

20CD723CF720

So I would guess php was writting it well, here is my php code:

```
<?php
require 'db.connect.php';
$idLeitor = $_POST['idLeitor'];
$leitura = htmlspecialchars($_POST['leitura']);
$timestamp = $_POST['time'];

$leitura_ok = substr($leitura, 0, -2);
$leitura_ok = substr($leitura_ok, 2);

echo $leitura_ok;

$updateQry = "UPDATE CardReads SET leitura = '$leitura_ok', readTime = '$timestamp' WHERE id = '$idLeitor'";
$cardRead = sqlsrv_query($dbhandle,$updateQry);
        if (!$cardRead) {
            die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        } 
?>
```

And what I get in SQL field is:

[SQL Field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMPYg.jpg)

Can figure out what is happening.

Comment: I bet at some point there is an invisible character in some of your PHP files outside of the `<? ?>`. Perhaps a line return or a tab. You should probably fix that, but you should also strip the answer on python side if you don't expect blanks in the answer: `page = page.strip()` will remove blank characters that might exist at beginning or end of `page`. Still, fix your PHP as well. _(Or rewrite it using a language that does not spit out random tabs and blank lines that happen to be at the end of your source files… insert PHP hate here)_

Comment: I don't think that is the case. Here what is being requested from the webserver if I use pyton requests instead `2016-11-16 08:33:01 0.0.0.0 POST /core/db.card.read.php idLeitor=1&time=2016-11-16+08%3A33%3A00&leitura=%00%0220CD723CF7%03%0220 8080 - 0.0.0.0 python-requests/2.12.0 - 200 0 0 15`

Answer (score 0):

I found out that python was really sending this special characters so I did this on the python script:

```
result=''.join(e for e in result if e.isalnum())
print result
```

Comment: That's just camouflaging the underlying issue, not fixing it. It will probably bite again sometime in the future, and you'll have to trace the root cause again if you have forgotten this.